# Generating form from Javascript-Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I am looking for a way to generate an html form from JavaScript data dynamically to send a regular post request instead of an Ajax call. This seems to be a somewhat rare use-case as I only find results for Form->JSON.

I am looking to do this:

```
var form = $('<form Action="/"><Input type="hidden" Name="data" value="5"/></form>');
form.appendTo($("body")).submit();
```

Just dynamically with data from a JavaScript object, hypothetical example:

```
var form = $.createForm({ action: "/", data: myData });    
form.appendTo($("body")).submit();
```

Are there any jQuery plugins or JS snippets which would generate the form?

**Update**: myData of course is a complex object, not one or two form fields, hence why I want to automate it. Right now I am serializing the data to json and posting it like described, but I would like to send the data properly.

**Update 2**: I am looking to do something along the lines of $.deserialize, just that the function should *generate* the necessary form, not just fill an existing one.

Comment: I don''t think you can find a plugin for this trivial task, why don't you extend the jQuery?

Comment: What does the Javascript object contain, and how do those properties correspond to form fields? It seems like it should be a simple function to write, just iterate through the object and append appropriate inputs to the result.

Comment: Take a look at knockoutjs.com . It might be a little big for your problem but it could help.

Comment: I love knockoutjs, unfortunately I am not allowed to use it in this project.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery itself is dynamic enough for creating DOM elements:

```
var $form = $('<form/>', {
   action: '...',
   html: function() {
       return $('<input/>', {
          name: '...',
          value: '...'
       })
   },
   foo: 'bar'
});
```

You could also define a constructor according to your requirements, something like:

```
var FormMaker = function (options) {
    this.$el = $('<form/>', options.props);
    this.$elements = $.map(options.elements, function (element, i) {
        return $('<' + element.type + '/>', element.props);
    });
    // ...
    this.$el.append(this.$elements);
    return this;
}

var form = new FormMaker({
    props: {
        action: 'somewhere',
        method: '...',
        submit: function() {
           console.log('submitted');
        }
    },
    elements: [{
        type: 'input',
        props: {
            type: 'text',
            value: 'aValue',
            // ...
        }
    }, {
        type: 'p',
        props: {
            text: '...'
        }
    }]
}); 

form.$el.appendTo('#somewhere');
```

Comment: While I like your creativity, this is a completely different direction from what I am looking for. I have an arbitrary data object and want to post that to the Server, much like $.post, just using a form instead of Ajax.

Comment: @manuFS Yes, the question was clear to me, it was just an example. As I hadn't seen an example of JSON structure I suggested a general solution.

Comment: The object is arbitrary, as I said. It could contain everything including Arrays of complex types and as such, building the form is *not* a trivial task in my opinion.

Comment: @manuFS Well, I meant jQuery can create elements dynamically. When jQuery is used, using a plugin just for creating form elements doesn't make a lot of sense. Sorry, that's all I can suggest. There is no magical solution/plugin that can guess what should be created.

Answer (score 0):

This function creates a form according to the object in parameter :

```
 function makeForm(obj) {
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.action="/";
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.name = obj.name;
        input.value = obj.value;
        form.appendChild(input);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aBzLS/1/)

Answer (score 0):

May I humbly suggest [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org)?

It generates HTML forms from arbitrary complex JSON objects. Simple JavaScript example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://metawidget.org/js/4.0/metawidget-core.min.js"></script>
      <style>
         #metawidget {
            border: 1px solid #cccccc;
            width: 250px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 50px auto;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="metawidget"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var mw = new metawidget.Metawidget( document.getElementById( 'metawidget' ));
         mw.toInspect = {
            firstname: 'Homer',
            surname: 'Simpson',
            age: 36
         };
         mw.buildWidgets();
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

It also supports:

- augmenting the JSON object with additional sources of metadata, such as JSON Schema or metadata from REST services
- frameworks such as JQuery UI, JQuery Mobile, AngularJS
- third-party component libraries
- pluggable layouts